# Android error - Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to read data from firebase but somehow I cannot sync my Gradle project.

I went to `Tools -> Firebase` and added Authentication and Realtime Database as a video I referred on Youtube.

But my Gradle project sync keep on fails after that.

I've searched this problem on google and tried to update my versions but it didn't work.

I also added `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` at the bottom of `build.gradle` file but it says it's an unnecessary qualified reference.

Here's some code.

1. build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2. build.gradle (Module : app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.el.ariby"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

UPDATE
Sorry I forgot to add error messages.

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0
Open File


Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0
Open File
```

I really wish I can sync the file..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please next time provide more details of the error, per console or xlint so we can evaluate the problem.
But I've already encountered an error that prevents sync, you use different versions of libraries causing conflicts. Please note that if you use a firebase library of one version, you have to use all libraries of the same version. The error is here:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1' // 15.0.1????
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'  // 16.0.3???
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'  //16.0.1???
```

example:

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3' //this is the same version
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3' //than this
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!. I followed your example but it's still not working..

Comment: it's just same.. I have no idea why it's not working

Comment: Hey, did you copy the new full gradle code from my edited answer? because it is impossible to give the same error
"-15.0.0" would never actually be found, but in the code I put here, I did not use that version.

Comment: I changed `firebase-core` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` and now it works well! I didn't touch anything else.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

with

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```